# How to have a JS function open a new HTML page and then run?

Tags: javascript, html, function

In a multiple-page app I'm building (coding student project), I have a requirement where a click on one HTML page is supposed to:

- take an input from that click, open a different HTML page,
- use the click input information (from the *previous* page) as a
  function argument,
- run that function and display the results on the *now-current*
  page.

I tried to use onclick on the "first" page to run the function, and then put the

```js
window.open("new_page")
```

into the function itself, but that doesn't work - the window.open method does open the new page, but it seems to "delete" all function results, regardless if I put window.open at the very top or bottom of the function definition.

What is the proper way to do this in JS?

Comment: Standard HTML pages are independant. If your other page is on the same domain, you can store the input value in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and access it from the other page.

Comment: You should look into the history API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: checkout this tutorial https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/build-your-own-interactive-javascript-playground this might help.

Comment: You could use PHP session variables.

Answer (score 2):

If your website implementation is exclusively client-side (without any server-side scripting e.g. PHP), here are two possible ways to do it:

### 1- Use localStorage:

Basically, `localStorage` allows your web application to store properties (as key-value pairs) in your browser, which you can access throughout your website. [More information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp).

```
//in the first page, you can set a property
localStorage.setItem("key", value);

//then from the second page you can access it like so:
var val = localStorage.getItem("key");
```

### 2- Add query string parameters to the URL you are redirecting to:

You can add GET request parameters to your redirect by simply appending a query string to your URL, so to pass a parameter called "key" with value of "value", you can do:

```
window.open("new_page?key=value") //the URL will now look like this
```

And then from the second page, you can retrieve the value like so:

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
var val = urlParams.get('key');
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using the "onload" attribute in the <body> tag of the new page to have the function run after the page is loaded, but your tip about using localStorage was critical to solving my task. I had heard about this option a while ago, but never got around to learning and using it. Thanks!!

Comment: @IgorB glad you got it working! If you found this answer helpful, please consider upvoting it. Happy coding!